# cKan Failed installation on restarting Apache service

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ckan

I have installed ckan from this tutorial http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html

until I came to part 4. Restart Apache and Nginx, I run "sudo service apache2 restart" and got this error:

- Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                     (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8080
  (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080
  no listening sockets available, shutting down
  AH00015: Unable to open logs
  Action 'start' failed.
  The Apache error log may have more information.

Can anyone help me with this out.

Regards,
Sounay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu error with apache: (98)Address already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745878/ubuntu-error-with-apache-98address-already-in-use)

Answer (score 0):

You're telling Apache to serve on port 8080 but get error 'Address already in use'. Sounds like you are running another server on your machine - port 8080 is a pretty common port to use for web apps.

You can see what is running on port 8080 like this:

```
sudo netstat -plnt | grep :8080
```

Now you need to move a server to another port number (e.g. 8081) - either the service you discover, or ckan.

To change CKAN's port, edit ckan's apache & nginx config files and replace '8080' everywhere with the new port number.